# How to add Kafka connector to flink through sbt of IntelliJ? I want to add the universal connector to support Kafka 2.3

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Below is by SBT configuration

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-scala
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % "1.9.1"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-streaming-scala
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % "1.9.1"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-table-api-scala-bridge
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-table-api-scala-bridge" % "1.9.1"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-table-planner
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-table-planner" % "1.9.1"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-table-common
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-table-common" % "1.9.1"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-connector-kafka-base
//libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-kafka_2.11" % "1.9.1" -- This not working and throwing unable to connect error.
```

Since I was not able to add the flink-connector-kafka via sbt, I downloaded the jar and put it in 
lib(created lib) folder in my sbt project. The sbt project is created via IntelliJ and only I added the lib folder manually.

Now, when I am importing the kafka connector package i.e `import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer` is working fine.

Now below is my code to consume from Kafka

```
import java.util.Properties

import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.{DataStream, StreamExecutionEnvironment}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer
import org.apache.flink.api.scala._

object KafkaFlink {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val properties = new Properties()
//    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
//    // only required for Kafka 0.8
//    properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181")
//    properties.setProperty("group.id", "test")
    val properties1 = new Properties()
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    properties.setProperty("group.id", "test")
    val topic = "flink-fault-testing"
    val flinkKafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer[String](topic, new SimpleStringSchema(), properties1)

    val value: DataStream[String] = env.addSource(flinkKafkaConsumer)
  }

}
```

I am unable to compile because I am getting the error
**cannot resolve the overloaded method "addSource"**

Please provide inputs as to where I am doing wrong.

Also if there is a way to get Universal flink-kafka connector directly via build.sbt of IntelliJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to specify in your SBT config is this

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-kafka" % "1.9.1"
```

If you leave off the "_2.11" then it should work. That's indicating which scala version to use, and SBT handles scala versioning itself.

Not sure why your code doesn't compile. Looks okay to me.

Comment: true, I just did the other way, I removed %  and left _2.11. Like this `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-connector-kafka_2.11" % "1.10.0"`. Thanks for adivse